# Is there a way for a `pip install git+https://scm.domain/package.git` to create a directory in the working directory?

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a package that I want to share to my internal team. I want them to be in whatever working directory and have a directory called configs/ created and a config.yaml with it, with a template.
My scm repo looks like

```
package/
    src/package/
        configs/
             config_template.yml
        __init__.py
        modules.py
    tests/
setup.py
README.md
MANIFEST.in
```

I tried adding the `include_package_data=True` key-value in setup.py, as well as `recursive-include src/package/configs/ *` in the MANIFEST.in
I want the working directory to look like

```
workingdirectory/
    configs/
        config.yaml
```

Along with the package being downloaded to lib/site-packages

Comment: Show the `setup.py` and `MANIFEST.in` files. -- But, well, re-reading your question: No it is not possible for a `pip install` action to create anything in the current working directory.